# reuse select menu with different ids' and names' in twig

Tags: twig

I would like to reuse a select menu, but change every time the id and the name for it in Twig. How could it be done?

I thought of a wrapper block about the select menu and then extend it each time of reuse. But how to set the values for id and name using `{{ parent() }}`?

Comment: [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I do this by storing and creating the keys in my custom `Twig_Extension` class, here is a small setup for it. By keeping it global I can ensure unique id's in every view/macro/include ...

<kbd>example.twig</kbd>

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
<ul id="{{ get_unique_key('my_menu') }}">
    <li>Foo</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

<kbd>ProjectTwigExtension</kbd>

```
class ProjectTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension {
    private $keys = array();

    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('get_unique_key', array($this, 'getUniqueKey')),            
        ); 
    }

    /**
    *   Create an unique HTML identifier
    *
    *   @param $name String to make unique
    *
    *   @returns String
    */
    public function getUniqueKey($name) {
        if (!in_array($name, $this->keys)) {
            $this->keys[] = $name;
            return $name;
        }
        $i = 0;
        while(in_array($name.++$i,$this->keys)) {}
        $this->keys[] = $name.$i;
        return $name.$i;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'ProjectTwigExtension';
    }        
}
```

<kbd>Register extension</kbd>

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new ProjectTwigExtension());
```

Comment: This is the other way around, so I give you +1. I would like to have a twig snippet and each time I call it, I will pass in a fixed string for id and name. So imagine, you have definded a block inside the snippet. And you fill that block when you call it in your template.

Comment: imho this can't be done in pure twig. I've tried 2 examples, but they failed. [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/sh8pi2)